# Collaboration without communication?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, game-theory, theory-of-mind

Is there any name for the hypothesis that likely minded actors can build and successfully execute a strategy that leads to their mutual win-win, without having any ability to communicate directly?
I remember that Stanislaw Lem based his "New cosmogony" on this idea, but I wonder if he used someone else's ideas or made it all up.

Comment: Like one takes the even-numbered problems and the other the odd-numbered ones? Or is even that level of cooperation against the rules?

Comment: @user4894 they can cooperate whatever they want, but they can't communicate each other. No way to send a message that says "hey, let's do this and that".

Comment: Well that's what I meant. Two people can divide up a task to their mutual benefit with only one agreement at the beginning and no further communication. I wonder if there's some kind of "zero knowledge proof" idea lurking here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof

Comment: @user4894 no agreements.

Comment: You might be interested in *tacit colliusion*, where companies in the same business collude to fix prices, for example, without the need for explicit conspiracy. The idea is that they all recognize the same market conditions and therefore act in their own collective interest without needing to meet in a smoke-filled room. See for example https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.6613&rep=rep1&type=pdf or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_collusion.

Comment: "Tacit collusion is a collusion between competitors, which do not explicitly exchange information and achieving an agreement about coordination of conduct.There are two types of tacit collusion - concerted action and conscious parallelism.[2][3] In a concerted action also known as concerted activity,[4] competitors exchange some information without reaching any explicit agreement, while conscious parallelism implies no communication."

Comment: Also see the legal doctrine of *Conscious parallelism.* "Conscious parallelism refers to businesses changing their prices to reflect the prices of competitors within a market without colluding or communicating with competitors." https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/conscious_parallelism

Comment: @user4894 that sounds like what I was looking for. Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll take a run at it tomorrow. If someone else wants to flesh out the subject that's fine with me, I don't know any more about this than the links I found.

Comment: You might also look at Douglas Hofstadter's concept of [superrationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superrationality), where players in a game make decisions based on the assumption that other players will use the same reasoning to come to the same decision.

Comment: It sounds similar to the [stand alone complex](http://pages.erau.edu/~andrewsa/matt_vargo_project2.html) idea popularized by a cult Japanese manga, but I am not sure how widely the term is used outside of that context:"*The Stand Alone Complex can best be described as an occurrence caused when a trigger starts a series of events by individuals that all move towards a single goal. In each event, the individuals are otherwise unrelated, and not directly in any kind of communication, yet all of the actions are concerted, as if coordinated by a single entity.*"

Comment: In a more formal setting of control theory such phenomena are discussed in [Puppets Without Strings by Varshavsky and Pospelov](https://mirtitles.org/2020/01/12/puppets-without-strings-science-for-everyone-varshavsky-pospelov/):"*We seek to present a popular account of the control problems that arise in complex systems which are more generally called large-scale systems in control theory. In systems of this kind, centralized control often gives way to decentralized control*".

Comment: In a way, any type of niche-making is a collaboration toward a possibly unspoken goal. Such could be seen as part of a hive instinct. Seeing a hole and then filling it is working toward a desire for completeness -- a desire whose mind may be higher than the individual.